# TERADATA: How do I use position function to return the position of a substring in a string

Tags: teradata

I have a string "Rj 0001 201410212014110301G 20141103ioR4564534 N20141021N 11R" in the table.  I would like to return the value "R4564534" from the string.
The query I use is:

select SUBSTR(columnX,POSITION('R' IN columnX),8);

but it returns "Rj" instead of "R4564534".
The result I'd like to get is "R4564534".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it actually 'Rj', only two characters? Not 'Rj 0001 '?

There's already an 'R' in the first position of your string, of course it's not starting with the 2nd 'R'.

What's yout Teradata release?

In TD14 you can utilize INSTR to start at the 2nd character:

```
SUBSTR(columnX,INSTR(columnX,'R',2),8)
```

If you got more complex rules you might utilize regular expression in REGEXP_SUBSTR, too.

Comment: my TD version is 13 so I can't use INSTR.  The string is not a fixed string as I have many other strings.  Other string I have for now doesn't contain "Rj" so the query works fine.  Only this string has "Rj" in the front.  Is there a dynamic way to only get the value like "R4564534"?

Comment: If you know that the string you're looking for never starts at position 1 you can use `SUBSTR(columnX, POSITION('R' IN SUBSTR(columnX, 2))+1, 8)`instead.

Comment: I came out with another question. I need to use CASE Statement for more conditions, but when I use case for this query, it doesn't return any value.  This is my query:  CASE columnX WHEN SUBSTR(columnX, POSITION('R' IN SUBSTR(columnX, 2))) THEN SUBSTR(columnX, POSITION('R' IN SUBSTR(columnX, 2))+1, 8) END

Comment: You compare `columnX` with `SUBSTR(columnX, POSITION('R' IN SUBSTR(columnX, 2)))`, of course this will never evaluate to TRUE. You probably want something like `CASE WHEN POSITION('R' IN SUBSTR(columnX, 2)) > 0 THEN SUBSTR(columnX, POSITION('R' IN SUBSTR(columnX, 2))+1, 8) END`

Comment: Thanks this concept works.  I change it to > '' because the result is character, not number.

Comment: The result of a POSITION is numeric, not a string. There's an automatic typecast from string to numeric, which results in 0 for an empty string.